# FFMPEG batch file to re-encode movies that don't contain string "h265" in file name?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a batch file that uses FFMPEG to re-encode movies to h265 to reduce file size.  I have a few videos that I previously re-encoded over the past couple of years.  I want to skip those and at the moment I just manually move them from subfolders before running my script, but this is getting tedious.  I'd like to add a command to my batch file that skips those files automatically.  All files that have been re-encoded in the past have h265 appended before the file extension.  My batch file looks like this, but it isn't skipping the files with h265 in them:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do findstr /v /c:"h265" "%%a" >nul && \
ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast \
-x265-params [parameters] -c:a copy "%%~na.h265.mp4"

pause
```

What do I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: I do `ffmpeg -i "videofile.ext" 2>&1 | findstr /lic:"Video: hevc" /c:"Audio: aac"` to test whether my videos have been encoded already.  `ffmpeg` dumps its stats to stderr.  You have to redirect stderr to stdout with `2>&1` to test the codec strings.  Actually, my tests get a lot more complicated, as I still perform the re-encode if the video codec is hevc but the audio codec is not aac, or vice versa.  I just add `-c:a copy` or `-c:v copy` as appropriate to avoid re-encoding streams already in my desired format.

Comment: By the way, in your production script, I hope you aren't attempting to split your command to multiple lines by escaping the line break with a backslash.  That's not really a Batch language thing.  You can split lines by escaping the line break with a caret in some cases, but not always, and never with a backslash in Batch.

Comment: No, I just didn't want it all on one loooooong line when showing it here.

Comment: I like your idea better.  I'm really only concerned with the video stream being or not being hevc so I omitted the audio stream bit and am using the following:

    for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" 2>&1 | findstr /lic:"Video: hevc" || ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "%%a" -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -x265-params crf=23:qcomp=0.8:aq-mode=1:aq_strength=1.0:qg-size=16:psy-rd=0.7:psy-rdoq=5.0:rdoq-level=1:merange=44 -c:a copy "%%~na.h265.mp4"